# R - Efficient way to read multiple files

Tags: r, subset

I have a bunch of csv files in a folder, each file having a date in the name of the file. I'm trying to extract the data based on a user defined start and end date. I have the following code

```
#Method1
f <- list.files("C:/Fileloc")
d <- data.frame()

#start and end dates are user inputs from Shiny
startdate = as.POSIXct("2015-10-01") 
enddate = as.POSIXct("2016-09-30")

for(i in 1: length(f)){
  filedate <- as.POSIXct(substr(f[i],5,14))  #File name example: XYZ_2015-10-05_ABCD.csv

  if(between(filedate,startdate, enddate)) {
    d<-rbind(d, fread(paste("C:/Fileloc",f[[i]],sep = "/"), sep = ";", header = FALSE,
                     blank.lines.skip = TRUE))
  }
}
```

Here's how long it takes to read all the files (366 files in this case)

```
user  system elapsed 
79.56   29.05  108.60
```

A quick search on this site led me to a solution which said that it's quicker to combine all the files into one .RDS file and then subsetting. I use the following code to do that.

```
#Method2
saveRDS(d, file = "Alldata.RDS") #d is the same data frame from Method1

dat <- readRDS("Alldata.RDS")
colnames(dat) <- c("Col1", "Date","Col3","Col4")

library(dplyr)
dat<-filter(dat, between(as.POSIXct(dat$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                       as.POSIXct("2015-10-01"), as.POSIXct("2016-09-30")))
```

And this is what it takes to run this step.

```
   user  system elapsed 
  58.81    0.36   59.24
```

The thing is, it takes the same amount of time irrespective of the start and end dates in the second method, whereas the first method will be faster if there are only few days in the date range. I assume it's happening because it's searching through the entire data each time.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to read/subset the data? Please note that since I'm rbinding the files sequentially before saving to `.rds`, the date column in the `.rds` file should already be sorted out by date. Can we somehow make use of that while filtering?

Comment: If read/write speed is what you care about, then use `saveRDS(..., compress = FALSE)`. You have two choices to make: save the files separately or all together, and save the files as RDS or as text. Consider those two choices independently. Do a quick test to see if, for a single file, it is faster to use `fread` or `readRDS` - that will tell you which format to use. Then decide if the performance of that method is fast enough to read all the data every time, or if it's better to have individual files so you can read only what is needed and then combine.

Comment: It wasn't very different. Anyways, I found out that the client will mostly be running not more than 3 months of files at once. So, I went with the first method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on posts yet so I'm answering here - a faster way for subsetting would be to use the data.table format:

```
d[Date %in% start_date:end_date, .(Col1, Date, Col3, Col4),]
```

That is when you already have `d` saved using method1. I find it much easier to refer to columns simply by the name instead of double quotes.

For method1 itself, I find it faster to use `apply` family of functions instead of a `for` loop. Use one function to parse all file names to get a vector of names that match your criteria (start date, end date) and then use `lapply(file_names, read_function)` to read all data.